# Error running a PySpark example. I think it is a Hadoop 1.x vs 2.x issue, but not sure how to proceed

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

I am attempting to run the hbase_input.py example for pyspark. This is the command I am using:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-cdh5.3.0-hadoop2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.jar ~/workspace/pyspark_hbase.py midway1 table1
```

I am getting the traceback below, which I think indicates that something I am using was compiled against Hadoop 1.X, and I am trying to use it with Hadoop 2.x.  I am just not sure what I need to recompile..(Spark?). Everything I am using is from a cloudera distribution, so I would think it would all cooperate. However, different people have been 'playing' on this cluster, it's possible a previous version of Spark, or something else, was installed.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/henry/workspace/pyaccumulo/pyspark_hbase.py", line 77, in <module>
    conf=conf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 530, in newAPIHadoopRDD
    jconf, batchSize)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1060)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1093)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$.pairRDDToPython(SerDeUtil.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can download Spark pre-built for different versions of Hadoop from [the official Apache Spark site](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

Comment: Have you tried the same script using Hortonworks' latest sandbox VM? I have the same issue when running pyspark on Cloudera. So I test the same script using the sandbox, BUT, still no luck. Same error pops up. If someone successfully ran through 'hbase_input.py', please let us know your hadoop / spark / HBase version.